# Spark: Dividing one array by elements in another

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark and Scala. I am trying to understand something here: -

I have one array:

```
Companies= Array(
  (Microsoft,478953), 
  (IBM,332042), 
  (JP Morgan,226003), 
  (Google,342033)
)
```

I wanted to divide this by another array, element by element:

```
Count = Array((Microsoft,4), (IBM,3), (JP Morgan,2), (Google,3))
```

I used this code :

```
val result: Array[(String, Double)] = wordMapCount
  .zip(letterMapCount)
  .map { case ((letter, wc), (_, lc)) => (letter, lc.toDouble / wc) }
```

From here: [Divide Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943428/divide-two-arrays-based-on-key)
This works. However, I do not understand it. Why does zip require the second array and not the first one also the case matching how is that working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does zip require the second array and not the first one?

Because that's how zip works. It takes two separate `RDD` instances and maps one over the other to create pair of the first and second element:

```
def zip[U](other: RDD[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(T, U)]
```

> case matching how is that working here

You have two tuples:

```
(Microsoft, 478953), (Microsoft,4)
```

What this partial function does decomposition of the tuple type via a call to `Tuple2.unapply`. This:

```
case ((letter, wc), (_, lc))
```

Means "extract the first argument (`_1`) from the first tuple into a fresh value named `letter`, and the second argument (`_2`) to a fresh value named `wc`. Same goes for the second tuple. And then, it creates a new tuple with `letter` as the first value and the division of `lc` and `wc` as the second argument.